# Object Mapping Error

Tags: c#, wcf, object

My First Model in WCF

```
public class One
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; } 
}
```

My Second

```
public class Two : One
{
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have Value for the properties of Model Two like this

```
Two obj = new Two()
{
   A="ww",
   B="WWW",
   C="EE"
};

One obj1 = new One();
```

Now i want to copy my `obj` object value to `obj1`.
But i need to skip the third value while copying in first object ..How To do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a copy constructor for `One`:

```
public class One
{
    public One(One other)
    {
        A = other.A;
        B = other.B;
    }

    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; } 
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Two two = new Two
{
    A="ww",
    B="WWW",
    C="EE"
};

One one = new One(two);
```

Comment: ya correct .except constructor any other way is there like using any datamembers

Comment: @Vinoth I didn't understand your comment. What does *"constructor any other way is there like using any datamembers"* mean?

Comment: now i am trying same thing in WCF .i tried like a `notmapped` datamember but no use..like that any other types

Comment: @Vinoth Then you should of mentioned that you're using a WCF application and you have restrictions with your code. Your question doesn't convey your actual need.